# ubuntu 12.04 LTS on inspiron n5110?

Tags: 12.04

I'm new to Ubuntu and I want to run dual boot ubuntu and windows 8 on my Dell inspiron n5110. I have gone through many sites for the installation guides but now I got confused because Ubuntu officially certified the LTS version for n5110 but there are some cases where people are facing issues and posting on the community.

Should I install Ubuntu 12.04 or some other version to my notebook? I also need to use Oracle.

Comment: try with a live cd/usb without installing. If you face problem post here so that we can help you. There are different hardware even if the model is same. So all the problem may not occur to you. 12.04 is a great version and I am using without any issue in my dell xps 15 (except optimus support as not supported by nvidia)

Comment: hi web-E as you suggested i used ubuntu for some time with installation ....i didnt faced any issues so i installed ubuntu 12.04 LTS dual boot with windows 8 everything was succesful...but after installation i'm facing two major issues...please help me with th regarding issues like battery back-up not more than 2 hours(in windows its almost 4 hours) and a slight overheat problem.

Comment: Do you have nvidia optimus garpahics card, then install bumblebee.

Comment: no i do not have nvidia i have only intel hd graphic card